# how to change the system property of java "java.ext.dirs" runtime?

Tags: java

I wants to append "java.ext.dirs" file path with my extension directory path.

I can do for "java.library.path" with below way

```
system.setProperty( "java.library.path", "/path/to/libs" );
Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" );
fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
```

But how can change path for the **"java.ext.dirs"** property?

Thanks,

Comment: I wants to do with this way http://fahdshariff.blogspot.in/2011/08/changing-java-library-path-at-runtime.html

Comment: Do you really want to do this? Java 9 will no longer support it! http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220#Removed:-The-extension-mechanism

Comment: yes i wants to support JRE5,JRE6